# Rails: How to show Web Previews when a link is added into trix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, discourse, trix, actiontext

I came across Onebox https://github.com/discourse/onebox - A gem for turning URLs into website previews. How can I use/build similar functionality for Trix Editor based rich_text_area?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend watching Chris Oliver's RailsConf 2020 advanced ActionText talk. The embed mechanism he uses for YouTube is probably the best place to start. You'll need to develop your own `WebsiteEmbed` model that is added as a TrixAttachment and has a partial that renders a preview of the website to your liking.

https://www.railsconf.org/2020/2020/video/chris-oliver-advanced-actiontext-attaching-any-model-in-rich-text [I wonder if railsconf.org has a bug, the url now has `2020/2020/` but was formerly just `2020/` -jb]